# How to properly use substring

Tags: java, substring

```
public static String updatePartialword(String partial, String secretWord, char guess){
        char achar = secretWord.charAt(0);
        char bchar = secretWord.charAt(1);
        char cchar = secretWord.charAt(2);
        char dchar = secretWord.charAt(3);
        char echar = secretWord.charAt(4);

        if (achar == guess);{
                partial = guess + partial.substring(1,4);
        }if (bchar == guess);{
                partial = partial.substring(0)+ guess + partial.substring(2,4); 
        }if (cchar == guess);{
                partial = partial.substring(0,1)+ guess + partial.substring(3,4);
        }if (dchar == guess);{
                partial = partial.substring(0,2)+ guess + partial.substring(3); 
        }if (echar == guess);{
                partial = partial.substring(0,3)+ guess;        
        }
```

This is returning values like "aaaa", a being the value that was input. The initial value for partial is "-----".  This is kind of like wheel of fortune. So when a user enters "a", the result should be something like "-a---"  Thanks.

Enter your guess: 
a
Character a appears 1 time(s)
You now have 150 dollars
a----
You have two options:
     a) guess a character
     b) buy a character
Type a or b
a
You chose to guess a character
Rolling Dice
Outcome is 0
Enter your guess: 
n
Character n appears 1 time(s)
You now have 150 dollars
a----n---
You have two options:
     a) guess a character
     b) buy a character
Type a or b

Comment: This is not executing like you think. Remove the `;` after the `if` expressions.

Comment: and its not a good programming practice to do any modification on the arguments.

Comment: @QuakeCore since it is a String no harm can be done..., hence the String passed will not be changed...

Comment: @PetterFriberg thats true in this case but I was talking in general...

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question, but have in mind also that you should do

```
partial = guess + partial.substring(1,5);
```

because the ending position you specify is not included in the substring, so with your code it'd get the positions 1-3.

Comment: Enter your guess: 
a
Character a appears 1 time(s)
You now have 150 dollars
a----
You have two options:
     a) guess a character
     b) buy a character
Type a or b
a
You chose to guess a character
Rolling Dice
Outcome is 0
Enter your guess: 
n
Character n appears 1 time(s)
You now have 150 dollars
a----n---
You have two options:
     a) guess a character
     b) buy a character
Type a or b                           Can anyone explain why I'm having this issue?